# saving managedObjectContext returns null error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Could anyone see any possible reasons why?

```
Friend *newFriend = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Friend" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
newFriend.name = @"Jim";
newFriend.age = [NSNumber numberWithInt:5];

NSError *error = nil;
if ([managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
{
     NSLog(@"error %@", error); 
}
```

managedObjectContext was passed to the view controller where this code is from the application delegate.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 if (![managedObjectContext save:&error])
 {
     NSLog(@"error %@", error);
 }
```

that should be

Answer (score 0):

You should expect `error` to continue to be `nil` if `save:` succeeded (and therefore returned `YES` as you're testing). What behavior did you expect here?

Comment: Thanks very much. I was expecting the behaviour that occurs with the !. Unfortunately just missed it.